# Solve congruence equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Solve the following congruence

$$20x\equiv12 \mod72$$

My work:

$(20, 72) = 12 = d\\
a' = 20/12\\
b' = 12/12 = 1\\
n' = 72/12 = 6$

$(20/12)x\equiv1\mod6$.

and now I'm stuck because of $20/12$.... Is it possible to have a rational number for $a'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using extended Euclidean algorithm, which is how you might have found out the GCD, we can do the following:

$$\begin{align}
72 =& 3\times20 + 12&12=&72-3\times20\\
20 =& 1\times12 + 8&8=&20-1\times12\\
12 =& 1\times8 + 4&4=&12-1\times8\\
8 =& 2\times4 + 0&0=&8-2\times4
\end{align}$$

And then if you back-substitute remainder to the second to the last line,

$$\begin{align}
4=&12-1\times8\\
4=&12-1\times(20-1\times12)\\
4=&-1\times20+2\times12\\
4=&-1\times20+2\times(72-3\times20)\\
4=&2\times72-7\times20
\end{align}$$

Then you can construct an $x$ by multiplying both sides by $3$:

$$\begin{align}
12=&6\times72-21\times20\\
12\equiv&20\times(-21) \mod72
\end{align}$$

Also, by considering the LCM of 20 and 72, we know
$$20\times18=72\times5$$
if $x$ is a solution, then $x+18n$ is also a solution. The general solution is $-21+18n$, or $15+18n$.

Comment: How come 12 x 18 = 72 x 5?

Comment: Sorry, $20\times18=72\times5$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Start by making it easier. You have $20x=72n+12$ for some integer $n$. That means that $5x=18n+3$. Now you have $5x\equiv3\text{ mod }18$.